# In saying "watch the aurora", how are "наблюдать за" and "наблюдать" nuanced?

Tags: словоупотребление

In conversation, I just said:

> Похоже, что это единственное место в мире, где можно **наблюдать за** северным сиянием, нежась в горячем источнике!

Or should I have said:

> Похоже, что это единственное место в мире, где можно **наблюдать** северное сияние, нежась в горячем источнике!

The thing is that I tend to associate the form "**наблюдать за** (детьми)" with the sense "следить", so I wonder if I should stick to the version without "за" when I talk about "watching the aurora / sunrise": "наблюдать восход солнца".

Answer (score 2):

'Северное сияние' is about both an object and a phenomenon. You use 'наблюдать за [чем-либо, instrumental case]' for objects and 'наблюдать [что-либо, accusative case]' for phenomena.

You will be understood if you say 'наблюдать за северным сиянием'/'наблюдать за восходящим солнцем', but it is better you use the version for phenomena:

> Наблюдать северное сияние

---

> Наблюдать восход солнца

---

> Наблюдать радугу

but

> Наблюдать за детьми

---

> Наблюдать за бабочкой

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two sentences is minimal, if exists at all, and different native speakers may give different explanations of the difference. Everyone has his or her own personal experience and associations with such nuances.

I would say that ''можно наблюдать за северным сиянием'' implies an opportunity to enjoy watching a clearly visible aurora for a prolonged period of time and that ''можно наблюдать северное сияние'' sounds rather like an opportunity to simply notice an aurora.

I would like to add that I personally would say differently:

> Видимо, это единственное в мире место, где можно любоваться полярным сиянием, нежась в горячем источнике!

This implies enjoying watching an aurora. If you want to say only about noticing an aurora, change ''любоваться полярным сиянием'' to ''увидеть полярное сияние.''

Answer (score 0):

According to Толковый словарь Кузнецова (*наблюдать*):

4th sense (осуществлять надзор, наблюдение ЗА) .. за детьми, за порядком. In this sense it's always with ЗА. But it's not your case.

1st sense (внимательно следить) is possible with or without ЗА. So if used in this sense, both variants seem possible. But the example in the dictionary is Наблюдать солнечное затмение. Maybe it's preferable not to use ЗА for observing natural phenomena in this sense, but it's not exactly clear. So I don't think using ЗА would be a mistake.

3rd sense (изучать, исследовать) is used without ЗА. So if one studies aurora as a scientist, it must be наблюдать северное сияние.

Your sentence doesn't imply scientific observation, so it's sense 1, i.e. both with or without ЗА seem possible. Наблюдать ЗА - will imply a more active way of observing, if it's without ЗА - you just state the fact.

Answer (score 0):

The both sentences are correct but they have different meanings.

'наблюдать за' translates as 'to monitor'. Watching without any rest.

'наблюдать' translates as 'to view'. Watching occasionally.

So

> Похоже, что это единственное место в мире, где можно наблюдать за
>   северным сиянием, нежась в горячем источнике!

means that you are searching for placing an scientific observatory with hot springs. But

> Похоже, что это единственное место в мире, где можно наблюдать
>   северное сияние, нежась в горячем источнике!

means that you're a tourist.